# Server with Supermicro X9SCL-F motherboard not powering on?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, supermicro

I recently bought the following parts and assembled them together:

- Motherboard: Supermicro X9SCL-F
- RAM: 4x 4G DDR3 PC3-12800E 1600MHz ECC-Unbuffered UDIMM GOODRAM
  W-MEM1600E34GSM
- CPU: Intel Xeon E3-1225 3,10GHz SR00G s1155
- HDD: WD 3,5" 500GB 7200rpm 16MB Cache WD5000AAK
- PSU: DELTA DPS-650HB A 650W

After putting everything together, I tried to turn it on by touching both PWR ON pins on the panel with pins, but nothing comes up. The motherboard is clearly receiving power, indicated by the lit up LE4 LED. The LE7 LED is constantly blinking, the LAN activity LED is also on, plus the PSU fans spin,. I should add that after touching both the pins I mentioned earlier, the PSU fans sound a bit different for a minute but then return back to how they were and an any additional fans I connect to the motherboard spin for a brief moment before stopping. Also, I replaced the CMOS battery but nothing has changed. I'd appreciate any help regarding this issue.

Comment: Verify you don’t have any bent cpu socket pins

Comment: I checked, and all the pins both on the CPU and the motherboard socket seem to be fine.